# Getting a FIRUser from their uid

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to get FIRUser data back from a Firebase by using their uid? For example:

```
let firebaseUser:FIRUser = FIRAuth().auth()?.getUserByUid(someuid)
```

I'm doing this because I want to allow a user to see a friend's display name in the app.

Thanks!

Comment: you should be storing this kind of info in your database in a `/users` branch, for example. The `FIRAuth` exists only for authentication porposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get someone by their Uid, you would need to store The data that you want in the database. You can use child["user"] with child["Uid"] to store things like a user's name or photoURL. Check out [this](https://youtu.be/guFW9aj4EHM) series of videos. He shows you how to do a signup flow with FIRAuth and FIRDatabase. The next video in the series shows how you query the data if you don't already know how to do that.